# R assign as dataframe and and to list

Tags: r

I'm looping through a vector with prefixes. I'm assigning dataframes in the loop, based on the prefix and I want to add them to a list.

This is the code I have. It works to initialize the dataframe and they also get the correct names. But how can I add them to the list

```
prefix = c("green", "red", "orange")

diff_list = list()
for (i in 1:length(prefix)) {
      tmp_name = paste(prefix[i], "_diff_tbl", sep = "")
      assign(tmp_name, data.frame())
      diff_list[prefix[i]] = ???
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: `for (i in 1:length(prefix)) {
  diff_list[i] = data.frame(paste(prefix[i], "_diff_tbl", sep = ""))
}`

Comment: You can use this code to generate a list of empty data frames, with `prefix` as the names `diff_list <- setNames(lapply(prefix, function(x) data.frame()), prefix)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the code below reaches your goal

```
diff_list <- setNames(lapply(prefix,function(x) data.frame()),paste(prefix,"_diff_tbl", sep = ""))
```

and

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(prefix,function(x) data.frame()),paste(prefix,"_diff_tbl", sep = "")),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep()` or `replicate()` to copy an object many times and store them into a list.

```
## option 1
diff_list <- setNames(rep(list(data.frame()), length(prefix)), paste0(prefix, "_diff_tbl"))
```

and

```
## option 2
diff_list <- setNames(replicate(length(prefix), data.frame()), paste0(prefix, "_diff_tbl"))
```